# Prevent highlight in list view

Tags: android, listview, highlight

I have a list view where I'd like to prevent the highlight on selection. The background color is set to be sem-transparent on the list view row layout. The more transparent I make it it, the more it gets highlighted in Android's default orange color.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="35sp" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
    android:paddingTop="10dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:background="#AAEBD5A8"

/>
```

If I remove the background and set the color like this,

```
private void makeListDefault(ListView listView) {
    int childCount = listView.getChildCount();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilight_no_gradient_correct_drawable);
    }
}
```

It's doesn't affect the color in any way. The hilight_no_gradient_correct_drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FF98FB98" android:endColor="#FF98FB98"
        android:angle="90" />
        <!-- 98FB98 is a shade of green -->
</shape>
```

Any ideas? I've also tried it with a selector, but nothing seems to affect the color.

Answer (score 1):

You can define listSelector as Transparent as:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

It will prevent the default color for the highlighted/selected state.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a custom color for background item of a ListView ?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/conversations"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:listSelector="@color/backgroundlistcell"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

be aware of listSelector="...."

backgroundlistcell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/listcell_enabled" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@null" />
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@null" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/listcell_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Maybe you will need to change drawable attribute value but this should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, including with the selector as   android:listSelector="@background/backgroundlistcell" from both the ListActivity layout and the list item layout, but it seemed to make the items completely transparent regardless of the transparency and or colors I used. It's possible there's something in my code that affects this, since I'm doing highlighting etc. from there. But, I couldn't get this to work.